# Create a new node when a field is added to a node

Tags: nodes, entities

How can a element (say an image) that is entered as a field (when creating a new node), also be created as a separate new node at the same time (either through copying the image or by referencing it)?

Comment: i know a way, but first just let me know why would you want that in the first place?!

Comment: Because that piece of content is relevant not only as a field content type X - but as a node of content type Y as well

Comment: what would the title of this sepearate new node Y be? the same title as node of x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option A

I myself wouldn't do that - I think that generally it's a practice that doesn't worth the time and risks (as would be explained in Option B) but anyway:

In drupal 7 this can be done with the [Multi Node Add](https://www.drupal.org/project/multi_node_add) module. There isn't a version for Drupal 8 yet; If you don't have the knowledge to port it to Drupal 8 you might hire a PHP programmer to do that for you. An alternative would be to copy the desired fields from 1 node to another [via this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone). This module is going through a porting process at this era.

Guessing that both modules work only on 1 content type at a time, and can't recreate content in another Content type: You could handle that by cloning your nodes inside the same content type (X) with [Node Clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone) or a similar module, and than convert all clones to their other, similar content type (Y) with [Node Convert](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_convert) or a similar module.

### Option B - Advice and workaround with Views.

As an [SEOer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization), I would recommend on finding other way to enrich your sites' content; Cloned content is quite a good recipe for lowering both your PQS (Page quality scores) and in some cases - Your PageRanks as well... This becomes more serious with every passing year.

It could be better to create more sophisticated content pieces based on the first node content via the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module (which is part of the Drupal 8 core); [Here is an intro to Views 8](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). Many tutorials are available in Youtube for that module.

Comment: The possible problem with Multi Node Add and Node Clone is that they probably work only if they are in the same content type **(never used them, just guessing based on module descriptions)**. Unfortunately, oper wants node from content type x to node of content type y.

Comment: I've edited my answer according to your blessed comment.